Query on snowflake sparks connector return error
I attempt to perform a query by using snowflake sparks, the code looks like this:
command = f'''insert into {NewTable} ({Newcolumn})
        select  {column} from {Table} {Where}'''
    print(command)
    df = spark.read.format(snowflake_source_name) \
        .options(**snowflake_options) \
        .option("query", command) \
        .load()

the print result looks like this:
insert into Process.dim_ICON (ICON,dim_ICON_Key)
        select  ICON, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ICON) from APIDATA 

however when I run the code it return error:
2024-12-01 16:36:44 ERROR    error:An error occurred while calling o302.load.
: net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: SQL compilation error:
syntax error line 1 at position 15 unexpected 'insert'.
syntax error line 1 at position 62 unexpected ')'.

where this error will not occur when it is running in Snowflake SQL
The script should have perform query
insert into Process.dim_ICON (ICON,dim_ICON_Key)
        select  ICON, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ICON) from APIDATA 

by using pysparks connector

There might be some interference how Spark connects with Snowflake via JDBC and the query parameter.
You can use spark.write method instead.
select_command = f'''
    select ICON, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ICON) as dim_ICON_Key
    from {Table} {Where}
'''



df = spark.read.format(snowflake_source_name) \
    .options(**snowflake_options) \
    .option("query", select_command) \
    .load()


column_map = '''Map(ICON -> ICON,
                    DIM_ICON_KEY -> DIM_ICON_KEY        
                    )'''

df.write.format(snowflake_source_name) \
    .options(**snowflake_options) \
    .option("dbtable", "Process.dim_ICON") \
    .option("columnmap", column_map) \
    .mode("append") \
    .save()

